# Which site is appropriate for questions about calculators and operating calculators?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question which is related to functions of my calculator. Which site should I use?

This is my question:

> What mode do I need to put my calculator and show decimal answers for square roots?
>
> I have Casio fx 991ms  Calculator that will not give me the answers to a square root. For example if I ask for the square root of 27 the calculator will show three times the square root of three as the answer.

Comment: Did you ask this via the mobile app?

Comment: Yes. I asked this question via mobile app.

Comment: The reason he asks is that a 1 rep user shouldn't be able to post here. It seems you found a bug :)

Answer (score 3):

To me, Math.SE seems the logical choice for this type of question.

From the [site's help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it seems okay to ask there.